# Can't display a `BooleanRegion` in the Wolfram Cloud Notebook

Tags: graphics, wolfram-cloud

I can't manage to display a `BooleanRegion` in the Wolfram Cloud Notebook:

```
floor = Block[{
  outer =Rectangle[{0, 0}, {2900, 6350}],
  x1 = Rectangle[{2900-445,0}, {2900, 740}],
  x2 = Rectangle[{2900-450, 6350-520}, {2900, 6350}]
}, BooleanRegion[Xor, {outer, x1, x2}] ];

Graphics[{FaceForm[Pink], floor//Region}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

It seems to produce a *blank* graphic object:
[image]

Do you think this is an issue with the Wolfram Cloud Notebook, or did I make some error in my code?

Comment: The region definition itself looks fine to me. However I am not sure the graphics can show a Region object. What does `Region[floor]` return? Does that display your region?

Comment: @MarcoB: Yes, Region[floor] does work.

Comment: @Marco Carl gave _the_ answer (as the current Mathematica version at least). That being said, it is somewhat counterintuitive to me than regions are displayed graphically in the Notebook and in `Show`--but _aren't_ graphic primitive nevertheless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [`Region`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Region) object is not a graphics primitive, and so it won't work inside of a [`Graphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics) object. On the other hand, starting in M12, a [`MeshRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshRegion) object *is* a graphics primitive, so you can use a discretized version of a region instead:

```
Graphics[{FaceForm[Pink],floor//DiscretizeRegion},AspectRatio->Automatic]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Carl. It works as expected, but isn't using `DiscretizeRegion` an overkill when working with such a simple region than given in my example? Maybe it would be better to completely avoid regions in such use cases, and work only with polygons. But that's probably another question... BTW `MeshRegion` does not appear in the list of `Graphics` primitives in the doc: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics#1953776833, or did I miss something?